# Android How to Check CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a TableLayout and I'm adding rows dynamically. And in every row, I have a checkbox and image. Now I want to check these checkboxes. For these checked items i will do different things how can I do it? 
Here is my View:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(array[position]);
        check = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
```

EDITED:
 actually I want to check the items whether they are checked or not

Comment: @nKn actually I want to check the items whether they are checked or not

Comment: then check.isChecked()... try reading the API docks, they can answer simple questions like this easily.

Comment: before asking question please search something on google!

Comment: @Hemant Chand Dungriyal ok

Comment: try this code,may help you-[check box link](http://conceptandroid.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-can-use-checkbox-with-listview.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
check.setChecked(true);
```

If you want to check whether the items are checked or not, use this one:

```
if (check.isChecked()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code `check.setChecked(true);`

Answer (score 0):

1.You should set the `setonCheckedChangeListener()` ,like this

```
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

In your Activity `checkout`

`public class checkout extends Activity implements OnCheckChangedListener`

Implement here

```
  @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Object tag=buttonView.getTag();
        //could be integer, or primitive datatype
        //just make sure of type-casting
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic,
        }

    }
```

2.Next set tag to checkbox, for more reference see here [setTag(Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
   cb1.setTag(anyObject);
```

which can be used to get some value on object to perform any operation.